# Why does more s-character stabilise Carbanions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

Since carbanions carry a negative charge, more the distribution of electron density, more is the stability.

What does this have to do with more s character?

Does the distribution of electron density in a spherical fashion more favourable than p orbital distribution, as it is more symmetrical maybe?

Comment: S-orbitals lie closer to the nucleus. Since the lone pairs are regions of high electron density they may be stablised by keeping them in an s-orbital closer to the nucleus.